# Что означает модификатор r' в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

```
arr = [list(map(int, re.findall(r'((?:\+|\-)?\d+)', input("Введите числа во вложенном списке")))) 
        for i in range (n)]
```

Comment: Кст, тут можно без `\ ` обойтись: `'((?:+|-)?\d+)'`

Comment: @gil9red, а `\d`? :)

Comment: @Grundy, не поверите, но `re` понимает и `\d`, и `\\d` :) Шаблоны `re.findall('\d+', '12 1')` и `re.findall('\\d+', '12 1')` работают и выдают один и тот же результат

Comment: @gil9red, какое-то странное выборочное экранирование :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**r** от слова `raw`, т.е `r` – это сырые строки (необработанные строки).

Нужны для того, чтобы слеш `\` не вызывал экранирование символов.

Популярные примеры `\n`, `\t`. Если у вас в строке есть `\`, который нужен сам по себе, то его нужно дополнительно экранировать самим `\`.

Пример:

`"C:\\Users\\Foo"`

Для raw-строк текст станет более человеко-читаемый:

`r"C:\Users\Foo"`

---

Сырые строки (raw string) – строки, в которых обратный слеш (`\`) не модифицирует следующий за ним символ.

Пример:

```
>>> print('abc\n123')
abc
123

>>> print(len('abc\n123'))
7
```

И:

```
>>> print(r'abc\n123')
abc\n123

>>> print(len(r'abc\n123'))
8
```

Как видно, для raw-строк `\n` – 2 символа, для обычных строк – 1 символ.

---

**PS.**

Описание [из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=raw) и хороший пример:

> If you don’t want characters prefaced by \ to be interpreted as
> special characters, you can use raw strings by adding an r before the
> first quote:

```
>>> print('C:\some\name')  # here \n means newline!
C:\some
ame
>>> print(r'C:\some\name')  # note the r before the quote
C:\some\name
```

Comment: что такое сырые строки?

Comment: и что такое экранирование символов ?

Comment: @Noob_Prog точнее перевести - "необработанные" строки. Сравните `print("test\ttest")` и `print(r"test\ttest")`. Во втором случае символ `\t` не обрабатывается (не экранируется, то есть не распознается как знак табуляции), а печатается так, как есть.

Comment: А двойные кавычки как вводить в случае `r`? Удвоением?

Comment: что-то ссылка битая

Comment: @Grundy, можно апострофами строку оформить `' " abc " '`, либо использовать тройные кавычки или апострофы: `"""..."""` и `'''...'''`. К ним `r` тоже можно добавлять