# С клавиатуры задать путь к файлу, из которого будут считываться текст

Tags: python

У меня есть код, который берет текст из файла, а затем на каждую страницу исходного pdf документа записывает этот текст, результат - новый pdf документ

Все это у меня происходит в данной папке. Как я могу задавать пути файлов?
Достаточно ли просто через input их получить и затем в качестве параметров в коде ниже указать?

Просто читал про какую-то "r" перед путем для корректной записи, поэтому появились вопросы

```
file = open('example.txt', 'r')
...
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("start.pdf", "rb"))
...
outputStream = open("destination.pdf", "wb")
```

Comment: Что мешает задать через инпут и проверить? 

Answer (score 1):

`r` перед строкой (типа `r'c:\path\file.txt'`) позволяет не экранировать (не задваивать) обратные слеши в строке. Это нужно только когда строка с путем прописана прямо в коде, т.е. как литерал.

Если путь считывается через `input` (или откуда-то еще), то r не нужно.

Подробнее про raw строки можно почитать в этом ответе: [Что означает модификатор r' в строке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908992/1365)

Answer (score 0):

Метод open() позволяет открыть файл, а для открытия файла требуется указать модификатор его открытия. В вашем коде указан 'r', что означает **r**ead, т.е. файл открывается на чтение, что не позволяет вести в него запись. Модификаторы также можно смешивать, например rb откроет файл на чтение в байтах - **r**ead | **b**yte. Все модификаторы описаны в документации к методу [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Очень рекомендую работать с файлами через менеджер контекста, это обеспечит закрытие файла по окончании работы с ним, даже в случае возникновения исключений.

```
with open("filename", mode="r") as f:
    content = f.read()
```

> Достаточно ли просто через input их получить и затем в качестве параметров в коде ниже указать?

Так как первый аргумент метода open() - это строка содержащая путь до файла, то - да, вы можете получить путь к файлу через input().

Comment: В вопросе речь не о той "r", о которой вы рассказываете в ответе.