# Парсер всех XML файлов в папке

Tags: python, парсер, bs4, lxml

---

Есть задача - сделать парсер для всех XML файлов, лежащих в папке на рабочем столе, используя BS4 и/или LXML.
Я новичок в этом вопросе, и единственное, на что хватило чтения документации - написать парсер для одного документа. А нужен такой, который пройдется по всем файлам (их слишком много, в ручную никогда не переписать, ибо файлы копились годами).

Ближе к сути - мой парсер считывает 4 тега в документе, и в дальнейшем он должен считывать теги вообще всех файлов, и сепарировать их по спискам (условный тег  в список 1,  в список 2 и т.д.
Пример текущего скрипта для парсинга 1 файла:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml


with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/folder/file.xml") as file:
    src = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")


uid = soup.find("prop", attrs={'name':'uid'})
print(uid.text)
language = soup.find("prop", attrs={'name':'language'})
print(language.text)
source = soup.find("prop", attrs={'name':'source'})
print(source.text)
PROFILE_URL = soup.find('PROFILE_URL')
print(PROFILE_URL)
```

Как это можно реализовать? Уже весь мозг себе сломал с этим парсингом...
Чукча не Senior, тапками не кидаться :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь составьте список из xml файлов  и пройдитесь по нему в цикле вставляя в вашу функцию путь к файлу .

```
import os
f = r"C:/Users/user/Desktop/folder"
e = r".xml"
g = [os.path.join(f, _) for _ in os.listdir(f) if   _.endswith(e)]
for a in g:
    with open(a, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        src = file.read()
.....
```

Comment: Странно, IDE бьёт синтаксическую ошибку...
Можно ли где-то почитать о описанном Вами методе?

В моей папке более 100к XML- документов, из каждого из них считываются по 4 тега, и тег "uid" надо сохранить в переменную 'uid', тег "language" в переменную "lang", тег "source" в переменную "source", тег "profile_url" в переменную "profile_url". В дальнейшем эти переменные улетят в БД, но это я умею, а вот создать парсер, который пропарсит все файлы и вытянет нужные теги, записав их в переменные - я не знаю. Документация не помогла, к сожалению :(

Comment: Поправил код, у меня работает.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1069: character maps to <undefined>

Весело :))

Comment: Проблемы с кодировкой файла, попробуй open(a, encoding="utf8")

Comment: Слушай, пошел процесс. Хотя бы ошибки на старте не бьет, только жалко не видно происходящих процессов. Пока все 100к файлов спарсит и выведет print нужных тегов, времени уйма уйдет...
И вот вопрос - у меня 4 тега из каждого документа, они через запятую в 4 строки будут выведены, как парсер закончит работу, или как?
Знаний в этих вещах пока очень мало и пути решения для меня какие-то необычные :))

Comment: Сергей, благодарю, немного код свой подкорректировал и все заработало, print выводит построчно значения из каждого документа. Осталось разобраться со списками, как эти данные отправить в нужную переменную, и потом загрузить на сервак :)

Comment: Рад был помочь! Удачи!

Comment: Сергей, подскажите пожалуйста, обязательна ли приписка r к пути к файлам и формату файлов?
Я планирую передавать путь к файлу как аргумент через командную строку, но не уверен, что это удастся сделать корректно в таком виде, в каком оно существует.

Comment: Привет! Можешь поэкспериментировать убрав r, а про "сырые" строки можно почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908989/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-r-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5