# поиск пдф для создания

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dataframe

у меня есть код, который выполняет считывание текста из пдф файлов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам надо составить список из файлов pdf, которые находяться в папке и пройтись по нему в цикле. Аналогия - [Парсер всех XML файлов в папке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1387807/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-xml-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5/1387833#1387833)
2. В  каждом цикле создавайте новую папку с именем, используя или имя файла или номера 1, 2,...  и сохраняйте результат в ней. `os.mkdir(name)`
3. Мне кажется надо разбить ваше сплошное полотно на отдельные функции - выделение картинок, таблиц, текста, так будет потом легче что-то подстраивать или подправлять.