# 'Системе не удается найти указанный путь.' при попытке войти в папку с помощью os.system

Tags: python, cmd

Я могу войти в папку bin через cmd, открыв его самостоятельно, но когда пытаюсь открыть bin с помощью кода, то выходит ошибка 'Системе не удается найти указанный путь.'

```
import os
os.system("start cmd /k cd C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\MySQLServer8.0\bin")
```

Comment: Используйте [r-строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908992/519463)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нужно экранировать каждый обратный слеш, используя еще один обратный слеш.

```
import os
os.system("start cmd /k cd C:\\ProgramFiles\\MySQL\\MySQLServer8.0\\bin")
```

Либо, как правильно написали в комментарии:

```
import os
os.system(r"start cmd /k cd C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\MySQLServer8.0\bin")
```

Comment: Либо: `os.system(r"start cmd /k cd C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\MySQLServer8.0\bin")`

Comment: @gil9red да, действительно, спасибо за дополнение