# Объясните пожалуйста, как работает данная строка в программе?

Tags: python

Встретился с данной программой на просторах интернета, как в ней работает 9-ая строка? (a = re.findall(r'Природные ресурсы(.*?)Почвы', article,re.DOTALL)). Если быть точнее, то что обозначают и как работают знаки и круглые скобки в ней?

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import re  
  
url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD'  
r = requests.get(url)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
article = soup.text  
a = re.findall(r'Природные ресурсы(.*?)Почвы', article,re.DOTALL)  
for i in a:  
    print(i)
```

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-re-python/funktsija-findall-modulja-re/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908989/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-r-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: (.*?) нежадный алгоритм . - любой символ, * - больше одного символа, ? - ограничить до "Почвы". Регулярные выражения в python3 - читать-изучать.

Comment: сами скобки - отбирает в массив, т.к. может быть несколько совпадений при поиске.

Answer (score 0):

Знаки в скобках (.*?) обозначают группу захвата. Группы захвата позволяют извлекать определенные подстроки из общего совпадения. В данном случае, знаки (.*?) указывают, что мы хотим извлечь любое количество любых символов между подстроками "Природные ресурсы" и "Почвы".

Comment: Звёздочку потеряли