# Python, модуль re, экранирование скобок

Tags: python, re

Есть строка:

```
'inlet_mass_flow_pATCH1(mass_flux)inlet_mass_flow_pATCH2(mass_flux)'
```

Я хочу отделить 'inlet_mass_flow_pATCH1(mass_flux)' от 'inlet_mass_flow_pATCH2(mass_flux)'. Для этого использую re таким образом:

```
re.findall('inlet_mass_flow_.+(mass_flux)', 'inlet_mass_flow_pATCH1(mass_flux)inlet_mass_flow_pATCH2(mass_flux)')
```

Получаю на выходе ['mass_flux'], а хочу получить ['inlet_mass_flow_pATCH1(mass_flux)', 'inlet_mass_flow_pATCH2(mass_flux)']. Как видите, не силен в регулярных, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так делаю...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скобки экранируются `\(` и `\)`, также нужен ["ленивый" квантификатор](https://habr.com/ru/articles/68345/) `.+?` (знак вопроса после +). И паттерн сделать в виде [r-строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908992/519463).

```
import re
txt = 'inlet_mass_flow_pATCH1(mass_flux)inlet_mass_flow_pATCH2(mass_flux)'
out = re.findall(r'inlet_mass_flow_.+?\(mass_flux\)',txt)
print(*out,sep='\n')
```

```
inlet_mass_flow_pATCH1(mass_flux)
inlet_mass_flow_pATCH2(mass_flux)
```